# ¿Porque sumar tanto los registros: AX, EAX RAX?

Tags: nasm, asm

He hecho este archivo asm:

```nasm
section .text
    global _main;_main es para window, si esta en linux debes usar start.
    _main:
        XOR EAX,EAX
        NOP
        RET
```

Es bastante sencillo, pero lo hice para ver qué hay detrás de un archivo ejecutable.

Lo compile con estos comandos:

```
 nasm -f bin arch2.asm
```

Y lo desesamblé:

```
ndisasm arch.bin
...
```

Y me econtré muchas lineas que hace lo mismo:

```
add [eax],al
```

Es como si nasm hiciera esto: `times 16 add [eax],al`.
Hay veces que despues de sumar tanto `[EAX]` por `al` sale esta instrucción: `XOR EAX,EAX`. Porque sumar tanto `[EAX]` por `al` si vas a poner el registro `EAX` en 0.

Lo mismo pasa en diferente arquitectura de la familia x86. Solo que cambia el registro: `AX(16), EAX(32), RAX(64)`

¿Porqué sumar tanto [AL] con [EAX]?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es curioso porque "`add [eax], al`" es `00 00` en bytes, a veces se usa como si fueran punteros para compartir memoria, pero no creo que sea tu caso. Prueba [en este desensamblador online](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly).

```
Assembly
Raw Hex (zero bytes in bold):

0000   

String Literal:

"\x00\x00"

Array Literal:

{ 0x00, 0x00 }

Disassembly:
0:  00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
```

Es como si hubieras desensamblado bits que no son realmente de tu código, puedes ver mas detalle ejecutando *objdump* por si ves que se repite `00 00`, quizás encuentres secciones como *.eh_frame* que se añaden para hacer profiling. Creo recordar que hay parámetros para que no te las incluya a la hora de compilarlo.

Efectivamente, parece que se trata de una confusión del desensamblador que no es capaz de diferenciar entre el buffer o espacios vacíos y segmentos de código cuando se encuentra con instrucciones de este tipo.

x86 ADD es:

[image: ADD opCode]

`d` es 0 y `s` es 0 en tu caso

La dirección local `EAX` para AL es también `00`, así que es pura coincidencia que también sean los espacios vacíos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]